# Dualboot: Grub fails to load Win10, but manual UEFI boot starts Win10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10, bios, grub-efi

My new Dualboot Win10 / Ubuntu 20.04 shows Grub and lets me boot into Ubuntu, but when I try to start into Windows (option `Windows 10 (on /dev/sda3)`), it gives me an error:

```
File: \Boot\BCD
Status: 0xc00000e
Info: The Boot Configuration Data for your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

When I check UEFI BIOS's Boot Priority list, I see two Windows Boot Manager entries with the same text:

```
Windows Boot Manager (SATA6G_1: Samsung SSD 850 EVO 500GB)
```

The UEFI< BIOS Boot Menu (F8) shows them as well. If I doubleclick on the first one, Windows starts normally. If I doubleclick the second one, I jump back to the main UEFI BIOS menu.

What can I do to fix the entry in grub?

**Background**

- After installing Dualboot Ubuntu 20.04 next to a Windows 10 installation, Grub would not load and boot streight into Windows.
- I fixed this with `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` in Windows command line and turning off Hibernation Mode and Fast Boot.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. And Windows often turns fast start up back on with regular updates, which sets hibernation flag and prevents grub from booting Windows. Boot from UEFI and fix Windows issues. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation Grub will also not boot Windows if UEFI Secure Boot is on. Post this to see details of UEFI entries. `sudo efibootmgr -v` expect your two Windows entries are not same.

Comment: @oldfred It says `EFI variables are not supported on this system.` So apparently what I thought was UEFI was in fact BIOS (I was just confused by the menu title which listed both). I guess that changes the nature of the problem - but I still don't know what to do.

Comment: Actually, Windows System Information says my BIOS Mode is UEFI. So now I'm really confused.

Comment: Many vendors still call UEFI as BIOS. Assume that is what users expect? But Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt boot mode since Windows 8 released in 2012. A few Windows 7  systems were also UEFI, but most were BIOS/MBR.  Also default boot setting in UEFI for installed systems UEFI or BIOS is separte from how you boot live installer. If UEFI always boot in UEFI mode. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred - Here you go: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QnYX435szx/

Comment: You have UEFI system and Windows in UEFI boot mode. But Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode and used Boot-Repair in BIOS mode. You must always use UEFI boot mode, and always boot installer or repair flash drives in UEFI mode. Your UEFI does not show a Windows entry, did ESP get erased? That would require Windows repairs. And boot live installer in UEFI mode, and in advanced options do the total reinstall of grub. https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix